# Backoff timer with URLRequest

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency, timer

I've implemented a basic backoff timer that increments the interval before next execution when the timer body fails. This works great for synchronous code, however, when I attempted to use this to retry HTTP calls, the timer is triggered only after a very long time. Is there a way I can fix this?

```swift
import Foundation

public final class BackoffTimer: Timer {
    static let defaultInterval: TimeInterval = 60
    static let minimumInterval: TimeInterval = 1
    
    private var isFinished = false
    private var isFirstRun = false
    public var isFailing = false {
        didSet { isFirstRun = oldValue != isFailing }
    }
    
    private var interval: TimeInterval = 0.0
    override public var timeInterval: TimeInterval {
        get { interval }
        set { interval = newValue }
    }
    
    private var backoffTimer: Timer?
    private var backoffBlock: ((_ timer: BackoffTimer) -> Void)?
    
    public convenience init(_ block: @escaping (_ timer: BackoffTimer) -> Void) {
        self.init()
        backoffTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: Self.minimumInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(executeBackoffInterval(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        backoffBlock = block
    }
    
    @objc private func executeBackoffInterval(_ timer: Timer?) {
        backoffBlock?(self)
        
        if !isFinished {
            if isFailing {
                interval = !isFirstRun ? timeInterval * 2 : Self.minimumInterval
                interval = min(timeInterval, Self.defaultInterval)
            } else {
                interval = Self.defaultInterval
            }
            isFirstRun = false
            backoffTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: timeInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(executeBackoffInterval(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
            return
        }
        
        backoffTimer?.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Now as said, this works fine for synchronous code

```swift
BackoffTimer { timer in
    print(Date())
    timer.isFailing = true
}

// 2021-09-30 14:44:45 +0000
// 2021-09-30 14:44:46 +0000
// 2021-09-30 14:44:48 +0000
// 2021-09-30 14:44:52 +0000
// 2021-09-30 14:45:00 +0000
```

But when I try to do the same thing with a URLSession request, this fails. At least the first time. When the `Self.defaultInterval` is passed, all (appears to) works.

```swift
BackoffTimer { timer in
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "https://www.stackoverflow.com")!) { d, r, e in
        print(d, e)
        timer.isFailing = true
    }.resume()
}

// 2021-09-30 14:48:45 +0000 Optional(209154 bytes) nil
// 2021-09-30 14:49:45 +0000 Optional(209153 bytes) nil
// 2021-09-30 14:49:46 +0000 Optional(209153 bytes) nil
// 2021-09-30 14:49:48 +0000 Optional(209153 bytes) nil
// 2021-09-30 14:49:51 +0000 Optional(209154 bytes) nil
// 2021-09-30 14:50:00 +0000 Optional(209439 bytes) nil
```

Comment: What is backoffTimer for?  All you have to do is run a `Timer` clock reatedly, right, so that one of those `TimeInterval` variables can count numbers?  But you are setting its repeats boolean value to false.  So you are not running a clock.

Comment: A backoff timer is a timer that has an incremental interval when executing. The use case I have is a bit more complicated than only that, but the general idea is, when the timer fails, start retrying after 1s and then incrementally double the interval when the timer fails again. Setting repeating to `true` will cause the timer to retry with the same interval it started with, whereas I want the interval to be a variable